# Windows 2008 SP2 Remote Desktop Hangs after April 2018 Updates

Tags: rdp

We have a couple of legacy servers running 32-bit Windows Server 2008 SP2.  Last week, I installed Windows Updates for April 2018.  Since then, we are having issues with remote desktop.  You can log on using RDP once, but if you log off and try to log back on later using RDP, the server will hang on the login screen.  During this time, you can usually log in at the console, as long as it is a different user that is hung using RDP.  The server will usually work properly at the console.  If you have a user that is hung using RDP, the server will not do a restart or shutdown, it will just freeze upon the "Logoff" part of the process, you need to do a reset or power off of the server to get it back up.

One of the April 2018 updates included KB4093227, which is for the Windows Remote Desktop Protocol (RDP) denial of service vulnerability in Windows.  I believe this is our issue.  I have uninstalled this update with the same results, as well as reinstalled the update with the same results.  Whatever it does, it seems like at least 1 of the changes cannot be undone.  Has anyone seen this?  Any advice, besides the obvious to upgrade to a newer OS?  Thank you.

Comment: can anyone shed some light?